# Placement and wording of Question Feed is confusing

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, feed

The `Question Feed` link on the right column is, in my experience, confusing in a few ways:

- because it is directly beneath the `Hot Network Questions` section I thought it was a feed of those questions
- I then realized it was separate from the hot network questions but thought it would be a general feed of questions for the site
- actually it is (I guess) a feed of events directly relating to the current question I'm viewing

I think the wording and/or placement could be changed to make it clear what is to be found in the link.

Comment: It does have a title "Feed of this question and its answers" which is visible when you hover over it.

Comment: And also it is separated from Hot Network Questions with the link of "more hot questions" in-between, which marks the end of Hot Network Questions.